# Can we use pair as the name for a vector?

Tags: c++, variables, std-pair

I came across an expression that states: `vector<int> pair(n)`. As pair is an inbuilt structure in itself, can we use it as a variable name in c++ and why??

Comment: `using namespace std` can be confusing, yes. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Here's the list of keywords you can't use: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: there's no problem using names from the standard library as long as you aren't using `using namespace std`

Comment: You can even have a vector called vector: `std::vector<int> vector{ 1,2,3 };` is perfectly valid code (if a little odd).

Comment: this very much depends on what headers you include and what using directive is in the code.

Comment: Very related, if not an actual duplicate: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)

Comment: The question is a bit incomplete, so we can't assume `using namespace std;`. It might have said `using std::vector;`, in which case `std::pair` is not brought in.

Comment: I don't understand the obsession with `using namespace std;` for this question. Even with that, you could do something like `vector<int> vector;`, it doesn't suddenly prevent you from shadowing a type name with a variable name just because the type name is in scope.

Comment: @chris it does if you want to use `std::vector` again in the same scope: https://godbolt.org/z/GWrf75nWd

Comment: @AlanBirtles, Yes, that's a property of shadowing, not of the using directive.

Comment: @chris that code would have compiled fine if you used `std::vector` instead of using namespace std + unqualified vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *As pair is an inbuilt structure in itself, can we use it as a variable name in c++ and why?*

That is not correct. The [Standard Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) provides a [class template called "pair"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) but that is *not* an **inbuilt** type and, furthermore, "pair" is neither a keyword nor a reserved word in the C++ language.

Furthermore, the aforementioned "pair" template is actually provided (in the `<utility>` header) in the `std` namespace, so its *fully qualified* name is `std::pair`. So, unless you both `#include <utility>` (explicitly or implicitly) and are `using std::pair;` (or `using namespace std;` – but [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)), you can use the name, "pair," as an identifier, just like any other non-reserved word.

---

In fact, even if you *do* `#include <utility>` and *are* `using std::pair;` (or `using namespace std;`), you can *still* use "pair" as an identifier, as mentioned the [comment by chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67263136/can-we-use-pair-as-the-name-for-a-vector/67263386?noredirect=1#comment118892043_67263136).

Comment: I'd say "_The C++ standard library_" instead of "_The Standard Template Library_"  though.

Comment: If you haven't included <utility>, that doesn't necessarily mean pair isn't defined in std namespace. It's possible that some other standard header you include includes <utility> or defines pair. unordered_map, for instance, certainly does.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Notice that I mentioned inclusion of that header, "explicitly *or implicitly*." From what I can tell, if `std::pair` is defined, it will be defined in that header (but I'd need to thoroughly check the Standard, to be sure).

Comment: @AdrianMole it's very possible that there is a third header that only defines`pair` (not other things <utility> defines) and both the headers (<utlility> and some other header you used) include that.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili [This Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) strongly suggests (Section 23.1, Table 34) that   "pairs" are defined in the `<utility>` header.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. The templates from the standard library are called `std::pair` and `std::vector`. They are not built-in, in the sense that they aren't part of the language, but part of the standard library. Hence this is not a problem:

```
#include <vector>  
std::vector<int> pair(n);
```

One can use using directives to drop the `std::` prefix:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
vector<int> pair(n);
```

Commonly used is also `using namespace std;`:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> pair(n);
```

Though, once you pulled the complete namespace into scope, the code can be rather confusing.

Read [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and try to avoid it. And give proper names. `std::pair` is rather common, so you better choose a better name for the vector, it certainly is not a `pair`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::pair` is not an "in-built structure". It's a qualified name from the Standard Library. Since it's qualified, it generally does not clash with your own names.

This is exactly why namespaces were added to the C++ language.